# Using variables with Mysql insert statement

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to insert some data into my MySql database and have successfully made a connection and submitted data, however my variables are saving as the actual name of the variable and not the value I am trying to assign.
I am collecting the logged in user of my asp system using identity and am collecting a score of a user from some radio button lists on my main page.

What I try to save the score with the id for a user with id of `12345` for example and a score of 4. it will save the word Id and the word score instead of the numbers.

Here is my current code:

```
    if (score != 0) ;
    {
        string Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" +
        "DATABASE=synther_physics;" +
        "UID=root;" +
        "PASSWORD=rootpass;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataReader Reader;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userscores (Id, momentsandenergytestscore) VALUES ('Id','score');";

        connection.Open();
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        connection.Close();


    }
```

Comment: You never pass your values into the insert statement

Comment: how do i get the data into my table then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that placing the variables directly in the statement is a no-no, leads to a very well-known problem called **SQL Injection**.
To avoid this we are going to change your command to use *parameters*, which will be populated with the variables later

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO userscores (Id, momentsandenergytestscore) VALUES (@Id,@score);";
```

We will then add in these 2 lines to populate the parameters with your variables

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", score);
```

As this is not a SELECT statement, no reader is needed. You can use the ExecuteNonQuery command which will return the count of rows affected (should be  1 for this INSERT statement.

```
int RowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hi there, thankyou for the responce, i have made the changes you suggest but am getting the error: 'Id cannot be null'

Comment: Try a breakpoint after Id should be defined, and see what the User.Identitu has for values.... Or defining before the if(...) and checking for Id as well as score.

Comment: id is null here, i think the code for collecting the logged in users id is incorrect. would you agree?

Comment: That would be my assessment as well. Try a manual over-ride of Id with something useful for testing iwhen its null, possible "NULL at " + DateTime.Now.ToString():

Comment: well it breaks my execution anyway as its the primary key in the fields of the table i am trying to use, ill maybe ask a new question if i cant find out a way of doing it. Thankyou for your help